# Как настроить виртуальную базу H2 для интеграционных тестов Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, h2

Я использую виртуальную базу H2 для интеграционных тестов на junit. Проблема в том, что эта база стартует перед запуском каждого класса с тестами. Допустим Запуск

```java
class ProjectSearchITP{

    @Test

    @Test

    @Test

    @Test
}
```

стартует база проходит 4 теста - база удаляется из памяти, потом

```java
class ContractSearchIT{

    @Test

    @Test

    @Test

    @Test
}
```

стартует база проходит 4 теста база удаляется из памяти.

Это происходит очень медленно так как у меня 64 класса с тестами.

Как делать так, что бы база поднималась перед всеми интеграционными тестами, и удалялась после отработки всех тестов? 
Прмер:

```java
class ProjectSearchITP{

    @Test

    @Test

    @Test

    @Test
}
```

стартует база проходит 4 теста ,

```java
class ContractSearchIT{

    @Test

    @Test

    @Test

    @Test
}
```

проходит 4 теста база удаляется из памяти.

Comment: Все зависит от того, как настроены конфиги ваших тестов. База будет использоваться только одна, если все тесты будут пользоваться одним и тем же конфигом. (В этом случае будет создан 1 спринг контекст для всех тестов)

Comment: Спасибо, не увидел к сожалению ответ, решил сам, но вы правы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо я решил задачу, Если кому то понадобится я сделал это так. Убрал все аннотации с классов тестов @DataJpaTest и сделал отдельный класс H2Config - допустим, название не важно, и подключаю его через @Import(H2Config::class) + к этому, так же на каждый тестируемый класс добавил аннотацию @SpringBootTest - иначе он не поднимает контекст с этим конфиг бином. В такой конфигурации база понимается 1н раз и тесты работают очень быстро.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, вашу задачу можно решить с помощью JUnit-аннотаций [@BeforeClass](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/BeforeClass.html) и [@AfterClass](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/AfterClass.html) , которыми помечаются методы, которые будут выполнены соответственно до и после выполнения всех тестовых методов.